# Spring's AOP is static or dynamic

Tags: spring, aop

As we all know, AOP is provided by CGLIB / JDK Proxy in Spring. Does the weaving happen at runtime, or is the bytecode modified at compiletime to include the advice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [Spring documentation](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.5/reference/aop.html), it is done at runtime:

> Spring AOP defaults to using standard J2SE dynamic proxies for AOP proxies.

Since Java's dynamic proxies work only with interfaces:

> Spring AOP can also use CGLIB proxies. This is necessary to proxy classes, rather than interfaces.

The Spring documentation has a good explanation of [how the proxying works](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.5/reference/aop.html#aop-understanding-aop-proxies).

Compare this to AspectJ, where the weaving happens on compile, which interestingly enough can happen [at various points](http://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/doc/next/devguide/ltw.html):

> The weaving process itself can take place at one of three different times: compile-time, post-compile time, and load-time.

In AspectJ:

- Compile-time weaving happens by using the ajc compiler to compile your sources.
- Post-compile time weaving happens by using the ajc compiler to add aspects to existing classes/jars.
- Load-time weaving allows you to [configure your aspects](http://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/doc/next/devguide/ltw-configuration.html#configuring-load-time-weaving-with-aopxml-files) without recompiling, but requires special support by the class loader (load-time weaving performs weaving when the class loads). It is implemented usually [via Java agent instrumentation](http://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/doc/next/devguide/ltw-agents.html), and performs worse than the other weaving times.

Comment: can u please elaborate on the differences? compile-time, post-compile time and load-time?